# OLA FFT Windows : Blackman-Nuttall or Dolph–Chebyshev?

Tags: window, fft

I found a web page describing all the existing windows for FFT. it's here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

it's very interesting as it shows the frequency response depending on the window used.

So when i look at the freq responses, i found that Blackman-nuttall and Dolph–Chebyshev windows seems the best

but what is the best of the best ?

and are they really better for audio processing than Hamming or
Hanning?

many thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Blow your mind here:
http://www.rssd.esa.int/SP/LISAPATHFINDER/docs/Data_Analysis/GH_FFT.pdf

I can tell you a couple of things on the matter.

There is no "best" window function because it depends on what your application is about. The common parameters on which you should focus your choice are:

1. Scalloping loss
2. Main lobe width (of a sine wave)
3. Sidelobes max level/decrease
4. Computational cost

For example, the simple rectangular window does not require any computational cost and it provides the thinnest possible lobe, but at the expense of a big scalloping and very noisy sidelobes.

Blackman-style windows are usually built to minimize sidelobe levels, but they tend to have a heavy scalloping. You might instead choose one of the so-called "flat-top" windows if you need more precise peak measurements since scalloping is usually less than 1% even with the simplest ones, but their lobes are very fat (6-10 bins in width perhaps).

Example Nuttall window in [0, 1]:

```
1 - 1.369982685*cos(z) + 0.4054102674*cos(2*z) - 0.03542758202*cos(3*z)
```

Example flat-top window (SFT3M) in [0, 1]:

```
1 - 1.84540464*cos(z) + 0.6962635*cos(2*z)
```

If there is a window function that has no scalloping loss, that is very narrow and with no sidelobes, then it would be extremely expensive to calculate.

Comment: Even with infinite computing power, there are fundamental trade-offs between main-lobe width, side-lobe max level/slope, and scalloping loss. You won't drastically improve any of these characteristics without making one or more of the other characteristics worse.